# How to setup VS code debugging in Windows when running WSL?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, webpack, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I cannot figure out how to setup debugging in VS Code so I can serve the app with node in WSL. I am using:

- Debugger for Chrome
- React app created with create-react-app
- Starting server in bash (WSL) via npm start

This works in that is launches a new browser window and the app is served, but I cannot set any break points. They all report `Unverified breakpoint`.

This is my `launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "React",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src"
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem seems related to webpack, but I can't figure out what I need to do differently.

Comment: Would you try to install & run VS Code in WSL? You can follow this instruction. https://dev.to/nickjj/using-wsl-and-mobaxterm-to-create-a-linux-dev-environment-on-windows-1omh  But I am not sure if that'd also require you to install Chrome within WSL...  Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Interesting idea. I have to convince my IT department to upgrade my OS, but this look promising. Of course anyone that might info on how to fix the original problem is welcome to chime in :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm about 99% sure this cannot be done: run react app under linux (wsl) and try to debug in VS Code under Windows. The problem is that the source map created when you run the app in linux is using linux file names, but VS Code needs windows paths. The clue was in looking at the sources in dev tools. When run under linux, there were linux file paths.

Initial workaround is to just run app under windows and I'm happily debugging now. Longer term is to try out what Sung Kim suggested and try to just do my editing in WSL also.

Comment: Could this [launch.json template](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/Debugger/gdb/Windows%20Subsystem%20for%20Linux.md#example-launchjson-for-launching) help? I have the same setup of using WSL and VS code, and this worked for debugging my C++ project. Maybe it can be also applied in other contexts.

Answer (score 9):

I have also struggled with this problem and found a solution:

**My Setup**

- Visual Studio Code 1.43.2

  - Debugger for Chrome 4.12.6
  - Visual Studio Code Remote - WSL 0.42.4
- React Application (create-react-app)
- NPM 6.13.7 running in WSL (npm start)

**LOCAL => WSL**

Use the following configuration in your `launch.json` if you have started your vscode instance locally (not using WSL) and want to connect to a NPM instance running in WSL.

```
{
  "name": "chrome-localhost-local-to-wsl",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "url": "http://localhost:3000",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    "/mnt/c/*": "C:/*"
  }
},
```

**WSL => WSL**

Use the following configuration in your `launch.json` if you have started your vscode instance via WSL (using the `Visual Studio Code Remote - WSL` extension) and want to connect to a NPM instance running in WSL.

```
{
  "name": "chrome-localhost-wsl-to-wsl",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "url": "http://localhost:3000",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    "/mnt/c/*": "/__vscode-remote-uri__/mnt/c/*",
  },
}
```

You might have to adjust the drive in both configurations. I am running everything from `C:/dev` so `/mnt/c/*` is perfectly fine for me. If you have your code located for example at `D:/dev/demo/src` you will have to use `/mnt/d/*`.

What helped me a lot to debug what is going on was the [.script](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug#the-scripts-command) command of the `Debugger for Chrome` extension.

---

**Update:** It seems that something has changed recently in the integration of WSL, Chrome and VSCode so the `sourceMapPathOverrides` are not required anymore. We successfully use the following configuration now for our WSL Setup:

```
{
  "name": "chrome-localhost-wsl-to-wsl",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "url": "http://localhost:3000",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
}
```

Comment: Mark this as an accepted answer. it worked for me

Comment: Is it also possible with this setup: Chrome + VSCode are on Windows, but Node Server runs in WSL. Serverdebuging vie remote connect already works but I just can't get client side code debugging to work.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a sourceMapPathOverrides to your launch.json.  It ends up looking something like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": { "/mnt/c/*": "C:/*" }
        }        
    ]
}
```